# How to set NSOutlineView to consider minimal content's widths with autolayout?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview, autolayout

I have `NSSplitView` with `NScrollView` inside it and view-based `NSOutlineView` inside `NSScrollView`, it has e.g. one column. My outline view must be scrollable vertically only and it must consider minimal width of column content to fit it. I think they must return `-(NSSize)fittingSize` with values `{minColumnWidth, 0}`, but it returns {0,0}. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to return the desired view size in `(NSSize)intrinsicContentSize`. I am not sure if I totally understand your scenario. You could add a screenshot or wireframe to make it easier to understand the setup. Whatsoever, take a look at my [question dealing with a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029052/autolayout-constraints-do-no-work-for-nsview-composition-with-drawrect/13034819#13034819).

Maybe also check out the **WWDC Session 232 - Auto Layout by Example**. It covers a new split view API together with Autolayout (starting around 41:00 minutes).

Comment: Sorry, I can't clarify that right now, but if I remember correctly problem is that I can not get proper fitting width of outline view and -(NSSize)intrinsicContentSize didn't help me. I'll answer later.