# Autolayout constraints do no work for NSView composition with drawRect:

Tags: cocoa, nsview, drawrect, autolayout

I am trying to apply [Autolayout](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/UserExperience/RNAutomaticLayout/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010631) constraints to a custom button which inherits from `NSView`. The button is rather complex and can be used as radio button for example. The user interface is composed in `drawRect:` as you can guess from the following code excerpt.

```
@interface CustomButton : NSView
```

...

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    // ...
    if (self.hasImage) {
        // ...
        if (self.hasTitle) {
            // ...
            [image drawInRect:imgRect
                     fromRect:NSZeroRect
                    operation:NSCompositeSourceOver
                     fraction:fraction
                    alignment:Alignment_LEFT];
        } else {
            [image drawInRect:imgRect
                     fromRect:NSZeroRect
                    operation:NSCompositeSourceOver
                     fraction:fraction
                    alignment:Alignment_CENTER];
        }
    }
    if (self.hasTitle) {
        // ...
        [self.textRenderer drawText:m_title
                         inRect:textRect
                      withState:state
                    controlView:self];
    }
}
```

I successfully configured a custom text field which derives from NSView. The difference is that the text field uses `addSubView:` to compose its user interface components.

I wonder if it still possible to use Autolayout constraints to position the user interface components. In the moment no component shows up. I have the feeling that it does not work because I draw those "subviews".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by implementing the `intrinsicContentSize` in `CustomButton`.

```
#pragma mark - NSConstraintBasedLayoutFittingSize

/**
    Returns a suitable size for the receiver.
    This settings may not apply if a layout constraint
    defines minimum values for the width or height of the element.
    @returns A size for the receiver.
 */
- (NSSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    // Calculation of width and height of the rendered text.
    return NSMakeSize(width, height);
}
```